# Retrofit2: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, retrofit

I have an error when retrieving json data with retrofit2 in Android Studio. Last time i was try to retrieving data with json only 1 Response model, but now i just need to retrieving json data more than 1 table from database.

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 20 path $.pesan
No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

My ResponseModel.class

```
public class ResponseModel {

String kode, pesan;
List<QuestionModel> result_question; //But the problem is coming when i try to retrieving another json from another table(2)
List<UserDataModel> result; //i was success with this(1)

public String getKode() {
    return kode;
}

public void setKode(String kode) {
    this.kode = kode;
}

public String getPesan() {
    return pesan;
}

public void setPesan(String pesan) {
    this.pesan = pesan;
}

public List<QuestionModel> getResult_question() {
    return result_question;
}

public void setResult_question(List<QuestionModel> result_question) {
    this.result_question = result_question;
}

public List<UserDataModel> getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(List<UserDataModel> result) {
    this.result = result;
}
}
```

My QuestionModel.class

```
public class QuestionModel {
String id_question, id_user, judul, waktu, tanggal, jml_like, aktif;

public String getId_question() {
    return id_question;
}

public void setId_question(String id_question) {
    this.id_question = id_question;
}

public String getId_user() {
    return id_user;
}

public void setId_user(String id_user) {
    this.id_user = id_user;
}

public String getJudul() {
    return judul;
}

public void setJudul(String judul) {
    this.judul = judul;
}

public String getWaktu() {
    return waktu;
}

public void setWaktu(String waktu) {
    this.waktu = waktu;
}

public String getTanggal() {
    return tanggal;
}

public void setTanggal(String tanggal) {
    this.tanggal = tanggal;
}

public String getJml_like() {
    return jml_like;
}

public void setJml_like(String jml_like) {
    this.jml_like = jml_like;
}

public String getAktif() {
    return aktif;
}

public void setAktif(String aktif) {
    this.aktif = aktif;
}
}
```

My ApiRequest

```
@GET(url_question_list)
Call<ResponseModel> getQuestionData();
```

Enqueu

```
getData.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseModel> call, Response<ResponseModel> response) {
            pd.dismiss();
            Log.d(TAG,"onResponse: "+ response.body().getKode());
            mList = response.body().getResult_question();
            mAdapter = new AdapterQuestion(MainActivity.this, mList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
            pd.dismiss();
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

JSON Format

```
{
"kode": 1,
"pesan": [
{
"id_question": "2",
"id_user": "8",
"judul": "Title1",
"waktu": "11:22:10",
"tanggal": "20-06-2018",
"jml_like": "0",
"aktif": "Y"
},
{
"id_question": "1",
"id_user": "9",
"judul": "Title2",
"waktu": "11:22:20",
"tanggal": "19-02-2012",
"jml_like": "1",
"aktif": "Y"
}
]
```

}

Thank for your help.

UPDATE: SOLVED
'Pesan' should be List<>

Answer (score 0):

In your `ResponseModel` you define `String pesan`, while in the json file `pesan` is a `List<QuestionModel>`

Comment: Yes, but that one is not called `result_question` in the json, but rather `pesan`.

Answer (score 0):

make some changes in response model class like below ..

```
public class Response {

    @SerializedName("kode")
    private Integer kode;
    @SerializedName("pesan")
    private List<Pesan> pesan = null;

    public Integer getKode() {
        return kode;
    }

    public void setKode(Integer kode) {
        this.kode = kode;
    }

    public List<Pesan> getPesan() {
        return pesan;
    }

    public void setPesan(List<Pesan> pesan) {
        this.pesan = pesan;
    }
}
```

and also make one pesan pojo class.

```
public class Pesan {

    @SerializedName("id_question")
    private String idQuestion;
    @SerializedName("id_user")
    private String idUser;
    @SerializedName("judul")
    private String judul;
    @SerializedName("waktu")
    private String waktu;
    @SerializedName("tanggal")
    private String tanggal;
    @SerializedName("jml_like")
    private String jmlLike;
    @SerializedName("aktif")
    private String aktif;

    public String getIdQuestion() {
        return idQuestion;
    }

    public void setIdQuestion(String idQuestion) {
        this.idQuestion = idQuestion;
    }

    public String getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(String idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public String getJudul() {
        return judul;
    }

    public void setJudul(String judul) {
        this.judul = judul;
    }

    public String getWaktu() {
        return waktu;
    }

    public void setWaktu(String waktu) {
        this.waktu = waktu;
    }

    public String getTanggal() {
        return tanggal;
    }

    public void setTanggal(String tanggal) {
        this.tanggal = tanggal;
    }

    public String getJmlLike() {
        return jmlLike;
    }

    public void setJmlLike(String jmlLike) {
        this.jmlLike = jmlLike;
    }

    public String getAktif() {
        return aktif;
    }

    public void setAktif(String aktif) {
        this.aktif = aktif;
    }

}
```

above code working only you provide json format in question if any error then pl provide full json from server given response.
because answer is based on question json format based.